# nested xml to dataframe

Tags: dataframe

I am trying to convert the below mentioned sample xml file to a pandas dataframe. I have multiple xml files which I will loop over to add all xml data into a single dataframe once i succeed with this single file.

xml sample file:

```
<annotation>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <filename>file1.png</filename>
    <size>
        <width>416</width>
        <height>416</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>label1</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>357</xmin>
            <ymin>116</ymin>
            <xmax>404</xmax>
            <ymax>175</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>label1</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>4</xmin>
            <ymin>146</ymin>
            <xmax>39</xmax>
            <ymax>184</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>label1</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>253</xmin>
            <ymin>139</ymin>
            <xmax>275</xmax>
            <ymax>177</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>label1</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>300</xmin>
            <ymin>145</ymin>
            <xmax>323</xmax>
            <ymax>181</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree

xml_data = open('path/xml_file.xml', 'r').read()

def xml2df(xml_data):
  root = ETree.XML(xml_data)
  all_records = []
  for i, child in enumerate(root):
    record = {}
    for subchild in child:
      record[subchild.tag] = subchild.text
    all_records.append(record)            
  return pd.DataFrame(all_records)

df = xml2df(xml_data)
df.shape
df.head()
```

Result:
[image: output]

However, I want the result something like this:

[image: required result]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the df you asked for.
Unfortunately, I could only manage the first row, as the labelnames are same (nodes).

```
resulting_df = pd.DataFrame()
file_path= "Downloads/dataexch.xml"
df_cols = ["Filename", "Label", "xmin", "ymin", "xmax", "ymax"]
rows = []
tree = ET.parse(file_path)
root = tree.getroot()
for node in root:
    #files = {}
    Filename = root.find('filename').text
    Label = root.find('object').find('name').text
    xmin = root.find('object').find('bndbox').find('xmin').text
    ymin = root.find('object').find('bndbox').find('ymin').text
    xmax= root.find('object').find('bndbox').find('xmax').text
    ymax = root.find('object').find('bndbox').find('ymax').text
    rows.append({"Filename": Filename, "Label": Label, 
                 "xmin": xmin, "ymin": ymin,"xmax": xmax,"ymax": ymax})
    #print(rows)
out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = df_cols).drop_duplicates()
```

Filename    Label   xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax

0   file1.png   label1  357 116 404 175

So, need to adjust the code so that we have other values as well, instead just the same xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax values in all the rows

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked but had to manipulate dataframe to get the desired outcome.

Code:

```
filenames = glob.glob("/annotations/*.xml") 
filenames = [item.replace("\\", "/") for item in filenames]

class XML2DataFrame:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.root = ET.parse(filename).getroot()

    def parse_root(self, root):
        return [self.parse_element(child) for child in iter(root)]

    def parse_element(self, element, parsed=None):
        if parsed is None:
            parsed = dict()
        for key in element.keys():
            parsed[key] = element.attrib.get(key)
        if element.text:
            parsed[element.tag] = element.text
        for child in list(element):
            self.parse_element(child, parsed)
        return parsed

    def new_format(file):
        return "'{}'".format(file)
    
    def process_data(self):
        structure_data = self.parse_root(self.root)
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(structure_data)
        temp_df.col1 = temp_df.col1.fillna(temp_df.iloc[1]['col1']) # Updating 'Nan' column values with specific value
        return temp_df

df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in filenames:
    xml2df = XML2DataFrame(file)
    df = df.append(xml2df.process_data()).reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.drop(['col3', 'col4', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8'], axis=1) # Remove unwanted columns

df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('annotations/new_file.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Thanks!!